# InverseFunction obtained from NDsolve : How to properly NIntegrate the solution?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, inverse-function

I am trying to integrate the solution of a differential equation, and i am not sure of the way to proceed correctly. (I precise i am kind of new on Mathematica, and that i have a quite unsufficient background in mathematics).

Here is my equation, f0 is supposed to be known :

```
DSolve[{f'[t] == ((\[Beta][\[Alpha]mut] S[t] - \[Alpha]mut)


- (\[Beta][\[Alpha]] S[t] - \[Alpha])) f[t] (1 - f[t])

, f[0] == f0}, f[t], t]
```

The solution that is given by mathematica is :

[image]

After reading other Q&As here, i understood that the K1[1] is equivalent to "t" in my case, as it is the variable over which we integrate in the solution.

To get this result, i did not specified S[t] to mathematica, but in fact it is a function that also depend on f[t] in the following way :

```
S[t] = -(((1 + \[Alpha]) (1 + \[Alpha]mut) (d + \[Alpha] - f[t] \[Alpha] + 
f[t] \[Alpha]mut + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))/(((-1 + 
   f[t]) \[Alpha] - (f[t] + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut) \[Beta]0))
```

I tried to specify S[t] in the initial equation,  and Mathematica gave me f[t] as an inversefunction.

When i try to evaluate this function by specifying parameters, i just obtain  something in the form : `InverseFunction[RealNumber + RealNumber * i]` but it does not really help as i'm looking for a value like after any simple evaluation (this value should be between [0,1]).

**Here the full example of the code i am running :**

i) The solution obtained by Dsolving f[t]

```
f[t] -> InverseFunction[-((1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
     1 - #1]) + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[#1] &][-t \
(\[Alpha] - \[Alpha]mut) (d - \[Alpha] \[Alpha]mut + \[Gamma] + \
\[Mu]) - (1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
     1 - f0] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[f0]]
```

ii) I rewrite the solution in a manner i am more comfortable with :

```
f[\[Alpha]_, \[Alpha]mut_, t_] := 
Evaluate[InverseFunction[-((1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
        1 - (-t (\[Alpha] - \[Alpha]mut) (d - \[Alpha] \[Alpha]mut + \
\[Gamma] + \[Mu]) - (1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
             1 - f0] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[
             f0])]) + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[(-t (\[Alpha] - \
\[Alpha]mut) (d - \[Alpha] \[Alpha]mut + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]) - (1 + \
\[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[1 - f0] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[
          f0])]]]
```

iii) I set f0 according to one of my initial conditions (and it starts to get ugly) :

My f0 is equal to :
[image]

Which leads to :

```
  fm[\[Alpha]_, \[Alpha]mut_, t_] := InverseFunction[\[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[-t (\[Alpha] - \
\[Alpha]mut) (d - \[Alpha] \[Alpha]mut + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]) + \[Alpha] \
(1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[1/(
       1 - ((1 + \[Alpha]) (d + \[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]) (d (r + 
              r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
           r (\[Gamma] + \[Mu] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha] - 
                 k \[Beta]0 + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))/(\[Alpha] \[Beta]0 \
(d (r + r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
           k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0 (\[Alpha] + \[Mu]) + 
           r (1 + \[Alpha]) (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))] - (1 + \
\[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
       1 - 1/(1 - ((1 + \[Alpha]) (d + \[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]) \
(d (r + r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
            r (\[Gamma] + \[Mu] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha] - 
                  k \[Beta]0 + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))/(\[Alpha] \
\[Beta]0 (d (r + r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
            k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0 (\[Alpha] + \[Mu]) + 
            r (1 + \[Alpha]) (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))]] - (1 \
+ \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
    1 + t (\[Alpha] - \[Alpha]mut) (d - \[Alpha] \[Alpha]mut + \
\[Gamma] + \[Mu]) - \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha]mut) Log[1/(
       1 - ((1 + \[Alpha]) (d + \[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]) (d (r + 
              r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
           r (\[Gamma] + \[Mu] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha] - 
                 k \[Beta]0 + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))/(\[Alpha] \[Beta]0 \
(d (r + r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
           k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0 (\[Alpha] + \[Mu]) + 
           r (1 + \[Alpha]) (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))] + (1 + \
\[Alpha]) \[Alpha]mut Log[
       1 - 1/(1 - ((1 + \[Alpha]) (d + \[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]) \
(d (r + r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
            r (\[Gamma] + \[Mu] + \[Alpha] (1 + \[Alpha] - 
                  k \[Beta]0 + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))/(\[Alpha] \
\[Beta]0 (d (r + r \[Alpha] + k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0) + 
            k \[Alpha] \[Beta]0 (\[Alpha] + \[Mu]) + 
            r (1 + \[Alpha]) (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Mu]))))]]]
```

iv) Then i create a vector containing parameters and ask for evaluation

```
    params = {r -> 3/2, \[Gamma] -> 3/2, d -> 1, 
  k -> 100, \[Beta]0 -> 0.3, \[Epsilon] -> 1/10, \[Rho] -> 
   1/10, \[Mu] -> 0.5}

Evaluate[fm[1, 1, 1] /. params]
```

Which returns :

```
InverseFunction[-3.20313]
```

It is like Mathematica does not try to get the Inverse before replacing values...
Any idea of how to process to evaluate it properly ?

I add that my end goal is to Numerically Integrate f[t] from t -> {0, infinity}; even if i assume it is quite straightforward once f[t] is correctly evaluated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide a fully complete, working example: You mention that you specify parameters - please show how & what values. Ideally, others should be able to simply copy & paste the code from your question to arrive at the point of your problem.

Comment: Only hope to solve your  differential equation is use : `NDSolve`. Symbolically(analytically) is not possible, because you have a **Transcendental equation**.

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for the advice, i edited with the commands i am running  and MariuszIwaniuk : Thank you for the answer, so i should use NDSolve to get values for my function, and use Nintegrate to get what i am finally looking for ?

Comment: What is: `\[Beta][\[Alpha]]` ,`\[Beta][\[Alpha]mut]`, `\[Alpha]mut` ?. What value have: `f0` ? You gives not all values for all parameters ? Be serious.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Oh sorry, For beta(alpha) it is a link function between the two parameters, on the form b(a) =  b0 * a / (a+1). I'll edit the post with the value of f0 i use in the code.